# How long does a nmap syn scan with the timing template set to -T1 take and is there a way to improve it's speed?

Tags: networking, command-line, port, nmap

I'm entirely new / excited to learn about computers, linux and most recently port scanning . After reading about nmap in a book, I began to read the manual & website of nmap, and play around with it by scanning my own devices (which i figured was the best approach).

I was getting not great results scanning the ports of my devices with nmap set to the standard timing, so I set the timing to -T1 (sneaky) to see if I would get different results because it claimed to help avoid possible IDS alerts in the device I'm scanning. The command I used was:

`sudo nmap -sS -T1 <ip.address>`

Now, the nmap website describes this type of scan as "extraordinarily long" and doesn't really give a concrete number of how long it usually takes. Is there anyway for me to speed up a scan of this nature? Is the time my port scan takes just connected to bandwidth or is it also the type of computer I'm scanning?

(Also does a port scan set to -T1 always give me more accurate results, and therefore should be used more often? Sorry for all the questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing option is covered by the online documentation: [Timing Templates (-T)](https://nmap.org/book/performance-timing-templates.html).

This should give you an idea.

But I think you should better redefine your purpose. By default nmap scans the 1000 most popular ports in TCP. That is still a "lot" of packets to be sent. Probably more than you need.
If all you want is to detect live hosts on a network you could send a ping request or some variant that can be more or less stealth and this will be much faster.

To speed up your tests you can do at least two things:

- use the `-n` option to disable DNS resolution
- do not scan ports or scan only the few that you need

First define your goal: for example if you want to find webservers on a network, you need to probe for ports 80/443. Not 1000 of them. If you only want to detect live hosts, you have different options. But keep in mind that some machines will not respond to a ping, either by choice or as a result of the network environment. Scanning networks is more art than science.

So it a good idea to learn by testing against a network that you own and control. If you know that a service is running on a machine but is not detected by nmap you will notice that the scan returns incomplete results, and then you will want to understand why and fine-tune your requests.

Also be aware that nmap does concurrent (parallel) requests. If your goal is IDS evasion this is one parameter to keep in mind. It's not just about the delay between requests but the number of requests made within a certain time frame.

My first suggestion would be to read the nmap documentation to get acquainted and even buy the book.

My second suggestion would be to sniff your network interface with Wireshark and see the packets that actually get sent. You will learn a lot about networking and better understand your actions. The other benefit is that you can record your captures, replay them, analyze them and also get some statistics (number of packets, bytes etc).

Comment: Thankyou! That answers my question perfectly